# What's the download size of the ubuntu-restricted-extras package?

Tags: ubuntu-restricted-extras

Just wondering what the download size of the 'Ubuntu-restricted-extras' package is?

Answer (score 1):

It is only 6.8mb in size so very small it is just some codecs for music and video and flash player.

Comment: Oh OK I was just unsure as I have always seen on sites it is like 300mb or 90mb or 200mb etc etc

Comment: I just checked by opening software center searching ubuntu restricted click on it click install and check under running jobs you can then cancle the download if you dont want it try for your self and it may be much bigger when installed.